# How to auto tweet from sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, twitter

I have a db.sqlite file that is updated live. If a certain value is saved within DB I would like to create a tweet based around this value. Any recommendations on the best way to do this please.

Comment: Please post your code and tell us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do it directly in sqlite (even if you could, sounds like it would be a very bad decision to shift so much logic into a database unless extremely necessary)

You can create tweets from Python though:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter